# How to receive email using linux, bash and imaps?

Tags: bash, smtp, imap, smtps

I have some email server which receives from clients via smtps (port 465, ssl/tls, normal passwort) and send to clients via imaps (port 993, ssl/tls, normal password).

What I need are bash commandos to receive/send emails from/to this server. I've already managed to send emails to the server via smtps. There are many examples. What I did not get to manage is to receive emails from the server via imaps.

Are there any bash commandos which could help me?

Thanks in advance

Goran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetchmail will help you. It is small and easy client for pulling mail. See here:
http://fetchmail.berlios.de/fetchmail-man.html

Comment: I've tested fetchmail so far. But one problem is still there. Fetchmail wants to deliver to a local smtp server which is not running. Can I somehow write the message to harddisk?

Comment: You can use `mda` directive to choose what to do with pulled mail

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to manually receive mails with simple command lines. You can try to use some tools tough. Like procmail or what the guy wrote at this address http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/receive-and-parse-email-in-bash-or-execute-script-when-message-is-received-769222/. Make sure that the port to receive mail is open on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it! Fetchmail & Procmail are my friends.